# Text based batch game demo, coding mistake

Tags: batch-file

Okay, so, I'm making a crude text-based batch game demo, its a sword-fighting game.... I've never used any sort of coding before, and I taught myself as best I could... I know this is a pretty primitive and easy to learn language, but I don't quite understand what I did wrong... It doesn't process damage to you OR the enemy, and the stat randomizer sometimes give out numbers equal to or below 0... Ive been tweaking, and changing code in ways I don't really understand, trying to fix it, so the code may be a little weird at some parts, feel free the constructively criticize, improve parts that MAY work, and PLEASE find the problems stated... (PS. its also programmed to recognize me as the "creator" and my girlfriend, and calls her by her nickname, but that works fine, so Ill remove it from this code.)
the code:

```
@echo off
color 02
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set file=AdventureTextMusic.mp3
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs
title New Adventurer
echo.
echo Hello Adventurer!
echo.
echo may I ask your name?
echo.
set /p name=
echo.
if %name% equ Michelle goto bunni
if %name% equ Stuart goto kitty
if %name% neq Stuart goto random
:bunni
cls
echo.
echo Bunni? Welcome to my game! I worked hard on it, I don't know if it will be good... We'll see I guess!!
set /a gold=%random% %% 25-1
echo.
echo Here's %gold% gold to get you started! I hope it helps!
echo.
set name=Bunni
echo Good luck %name%!
pause
goto continue
:kitty
cls
echo.
echo Creator? Bug fixing I assume? I hope all is well in the land of Adventure Text! Good luck!
set /a gold=%random% %% 25-1
echo.
echo Here's %gold% gold to get you started! I hope it helps!
pause
goto continue
:random
cls
echo.
echo That name suits you! Welcome %name%! To the land of Adventure Text!
set /a gold=%random% %% 15-1
echo.
echo Here's %gold% gold to get you started! I hope it helps!
echo.
echo Good luck %name%!
pause
goto continue
:continue
cls
echo The controls are simple, when it asks for your choice of attack, pick an option.
echo.
echo Slash does your weapons default damage, minus enemy armor strength, and takes no stamina
echo.
echo Slice does your weapons default damage, ignoring armor strength, and takes 2 stamina
echo.
echo whereas Stab does 1.5 damage, ignoring armor strength, but takes 4 stamina
echo.
pause 
cls
echo.
echo Would you like to begin, %name%?
pause
title %name%'s Quest
cls
set /a health=%random% %% 15-1 +2
set /a armor=%random% %% 2-1 +2
set /a damage=%random% %% 4-2 +2
set /a stamina=%random% %% 15-8 +2
echo.
echo Health: %health% Gold: %gold% Armor Strength: %armor% Damage per Hit: %damage% Stamina: %stamina%
pause
cls
echo.
set /a number=%random% %% 2-1
if %number% equ 1 goto Grunt
if %number% equ 2 goto Guard
:Guard
set enemy=Guard
set EHealth=12
set EArmor=1
set EDamage=1
goto battle1
:Grunt
set enemy=Grunt
set EHealth=10
set EArmor=0
set EDamage=2
goto battle1
:battle1
echo An enemy %enemy% has spotted you!
echo Enemy Health: %EHealth% Enemy Armor Strength: %EArmor% Enemy Damage: %EDamage%
pause
cls
echo.
goto turn1
:turn1
echo What would you like to do?
echo 1) Slash
echo 2) Slice
echo 3) Stab
set /p attack=
if %attack% equ 1 goto slash 
if %attack% equ 2 goto slice
if %attack% equ 3 goto stab
:turn2
echo Health: !health! Stamina: !stamina!
if !EHealth! leq 0 goto end
echo Enemy Health: !EHealth!
echo Enemy turn!
pause
cls
goto enemy
:enemy
set /a EAttack=%random% %% 3-1
if %EAttack% equ 1 goto Eslash
if %EAttack% equ 2 goto Eslice
if %EAttack% equ 3 goto Estab
if %EAttack% neq 3 goto enemy
:Eslash
set health-=!EDamage!-!armor!
if !health1 leq 0 goto lose
goto turn1
:Eslice
set health-=!EDamage!
if !health! leq 0 goto lose
goto turn1
:Estab
set EDamage*=1.5
set health-=!EDamage!
set EDamage/=1.5
if !health! leq 0 goto lose
goto turn1
:slash
set EHealth-=!damage!-!EArmor! 
goto turn2
:slice
if %stamina% lss 2 cls
if %stamina% lss 2 echo.
if %stamina% lss 2 echo You do not have enough stamina to Slice
if %stamina% lss 2 goto turn1
set EHealth-=!damage!
set stamina-=2
goto turn2
:stab
if %stamina% lss 4 cls
if %stamina% lss 4 echo.
if %stamina% lss 4 echo You do not have enough stamina to Stab
if %stamina% lss 4 goto turn1
set damage*=1.5
set EHealth-=!damage!
set damage/=1.5
set stamina-=4-2
goto turn2
:lose
cls
echo.
echo Im sorry %name%... but you lost...
pause
cls
echo This game is in pre-alpha, I will likely be updating it to add the full story.
echo Created by: SteweeBee
pause
taskkill /f /im "wscript.exe"
exit
:end
cls
echo.
echo ----       ----       ----  [----]  -------  ----
echo \   \     /    \     /   /   I  I   I      \ I  I
echo  \   \   /      \   /   /    I  I   I   I\  \I  I
echo   \   \_/   /\   \_/   /     I  I   I   I \  I  I
echo    \       /  \       /      I  I   I   I  \    I
echo     ------     ------       [----]  I___I   \___I
pause
cls
echo This game is in pre-alpha, I will likely be updating it to add the full story.
echo Created by: SteweeBee
pause
taskkill /f /im "wscript.exe"
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

```
set /a health=%random% %% 15-1 +2
```

The line above is the same as

```
set /a health=%random% %% 16
```

and I think you want this:

```
set /a health=(%random% %% 15-1) +2
```

The line below uses delayed expansion but you don't use code that requires it (like in loops) - You could just use normal expansion like `%health%`

```
!health!
```

This code will work, unless another character is added when typing and then it will fail. The variable `attack` should also be initialised before the `set /p` because `set /p` will remember what it was the last time through if `enter` is pressed without input.  Input like `1 2` with the space will cause it to fail too (ditto with `&`).

```
set /p attack=
if %attack% equ 1 goto slash 
if %attack% equ 2 goto slice
if %attack% equ 3 goto stab
```

It should really have a check for invalid input at the end - just a `goto :get_input` to loop back for input will do.